# Flutter how to make a full height column scrollable when the window height smaller than a certain value

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve a full height column which there is some element stick to bottom.

But I also want the whole column scrollable when window size is smaller than certain value

below is my attempt, but not work:

```
body: Container(
        color: const Color(0xffCECECE),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
                child: BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) {
                    return LoginBloc(
                      authenticationRepository:
                          RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(
                              context),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const LoginForm(),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                child:
                    const Text('My App bottom'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

So how to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The widget structure will

```
body:
   Column
     Expanded get available height
      SingleChildScrollView
        Column
     
     BottomWidget
```

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffCECECE),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          // child: BlocProvider( //you can include column here
          //   create: (context) {
          //     return LoginBloc(
          //       authenticationRepository:
          //           RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(
          //               context),
          //     );
          //   },
          //   child: const LoginForm(),
          // ),
        ),
      ),
      const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
        child: Text('My App bottom'),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: can I also make the bottom scroll with the content?
What I want is the whole column scrollable.

Comment: Yes, but you wanted *element stick to bottom.*. on full scrollable case, you need to provide fixed size I think

Comment: oh, so you mean what I ask is not possible in flutter?

Comment: I may not be aware but there are N possible way to get certain thing. It would be easy for me to get if you include a gif/images that will represent what exactly you are trying to get.

Comment: Let say I have a Header, Content, and Bottom widgets, layout inside a column. I would like, if the height of the window is smaller than 450, the column is scrollable.
On the other hand, if the height is larger 450, I would like, there is a Expanded between Content and Bottom, so that the Bottom sticks at the bottom, and no scroll bar, like so: Header, Content, Expanded and Bottom

ps. the Expanded is not a requirement, what I want is just make the Bottom stick at bottom.

Is this clear enough? Thanks